# Orchard Dependency Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms

I am currently having an issue with dependencies between modules in Orchard. If I just set the reference in the module it works fine, but once I try to make a method call to the other module I get this error:

> Orchard.Environment.DefaultBuildManager - (null) - Error when
>   compiling assembly under
>   ~/Modules/ExampleProject.Reservations/ExampleProject.Reservations.csproj.
>       System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): f:\ExampleProject\Example
>   Company\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\ExampleProject.Reservations\ViewModels\ReservationViewModel.cs(19):
>   error CS0433: The type
>   'ExampleProject.Utils.Attributes.OrchardLocalizedDisplayName' exists
>   in both 'c:\Users\Sammi\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\orchardlocal\fa2342db\ec2b909e\App_Web_0db0qcdx.dll' and
>   'f:\ExampleProject\Example
>   Company\src\Orchard.Web\App_Data\Dependencies\ExampleProject.Utils.dll'
>          at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledAssembly(String
>   virtualPath)
>          at Orchard.Environment.DefaultBuildManager.GetCompiledAssembly(String
>   virtualPath) in f:\ExampleProject\Example
>   Company\src\Orchard\Environment\IBuildManager.cs:line 53

I've tried removing the dependencies folder, cleaning and rebuilding the solution and it still doesn't seem to work. I've also tried setting dynamic module compilation to false.

Any ideas here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess would be that you referenced the dll instead of referencing the project.

Comment: I'm referencing the project.

Comment: Delete your temporary asp.net files and try again.

Comment: Just tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you making the method call from?

Comment: Have you recently renamed the module by chance? Such errors can happen if you don't rename everything, e.g. still have the old default namespace in the csproj.

Comment: First, could you please clarify what modules do you have - it seems like there are two of them - `ExampleProject.Reservations` and `ExampleProject.Utils` and you reference the latter in the former, right? Also check if folder names in /Modules and names of .csproj files inside those match exactly - there may be some leftovers that force dynamic compilation.

Comment: That is correct, Reservations has a reference to Utils and I am calling methods from the utils project in there. I have double checked the folder names and csproj file names and it all seems to be in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new module through command line and moving all of the code from the old one in there. The module I had was renamed from an older one, so not sure if that had something to do with it.